# Port forwarding to public and allow an IP

Tags: security, router, port-forwarding

I wanted to share my local computer's remote desktop tcp port 3389 to the internet and access to it from a remote computer when I'm not in the home.

But just sharing port to public without any security is a bad idea probably, preferably I want to have a IP restriction to the port, since I know what IP(s) I want to access from and they are typically fixed.

Is there any way to do port forwarding a port to the internet with an allow IPs function?
Or do I need to buy a supported wifi router for that?

Just in case note this: I use a router TP link Archer c1200
Also, I know a VPN way to do that stuff but VPN way didn't work for me well so would like to go with this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular router, but my guess is that it won't be possible to do what you're asking with it. Enterprise-grade or even small business class firewalls? Absolutely. But consumer-grade routers usually don't offer that much configurability. It may be possible with 3rd party firmware, like DD-WRT, assuming your device is supported.

However, it would be much easier to setup a VPN server on your LAN (I recommend https://www.pivpn.io/ for its ease of use) and only allow RDP connections from that LAN.